# Which version of a managed package @RestResource class is used to handle a REST request?

Tags: managed-package, rest-service

I have recently added some `@RestResource` classes to a managed package and the implementations have been changing from version to version of the managed package.

I had assumed that when the managed package is installed it would always be the version of the `@RestResource` from the latest version of the managed package that would be used when a REST request is handled. But I have one example where this did not appear to be the case.

Is the versioning behavior for this situation documented anywhere?

Comment: Hey Keith, could you explain more of the details of the example that didn't meet your expectations?

Comment: Sure. I added some debug logging to the class, created a new package version and deployed it. When invoking over HTTP the logging did not appear. When invoking from the developer console via Apex it did. (Detailed logging for the managed package was turned on via a case.) Got me concerned about what the versioning model is.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  I'm running into something similar right now.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Sorry, as far as I remember I didn't get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Did it resolve itself over time?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Sorry again - no recollection as it was 5 years ago.