# Is there a way to specify an API version of a call to @RestResource?

Tags: apexrest, territory-management, restresource, api-version

I would like to specify an API version when I call a @RestResource via an API.  Is that possible?

#### Why

For some reason, our Spring '19 sandbox is having a weird issue, and I'd like to fix this before production becomes Spring.  We put in a support ticket, but I wonder if someone else has hit this issue and solved it, or if it's a known issue that will be fixed before release.

We have enabled Enterprise Territory Management in our org, and we have a class `MyRestResource` that references `UserTerritory2Association`. `MyRestResource` is a `@RestResource`.  When we hit the resource in a unit test, it works just fine, but when we hit it via REST API, it fails.

This works in Winter '19, but not in Spring '19 sandbox.

Here's a minimally-viable failure of this test.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/my-resource')
global class MyRestResource {
  @HttpPost
  global static void doIt() {
    UserTerritory2Association assoc = null;
  }
}
```

> Here's a similar issue:
>
> ([Which version of a managed package @RestResource class is used to handle a REST request?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23187/which-version-of-a-managed-package-restresource-class-is-used-to-handle-a-rest))

Comment: Have you tried varying the API version defined in the REST resource URL? E.g. `/services/data/v43.0/tooling`. Also, what is the API version for the class that defines the REST resource set to?

Comment: @DanielBallinger The API version of the ApexClass is not different on either deployment.  It's 43.0!  That seems to be irrelevant to this particular bug.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Just tried adding v43.0 all over the path and it was all 404's.